# How to draw a simple Argand diagram in Python?

Tags: python, math, jupyter-notebook, visualization, complex-numbers

An Argand diagram is a simple representation of complex numbers on the Cartesian X-Y grid, as shown here:

[image: Argand Diagram from Wolfram MathWorld]

It's just a unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$; we commonly use it as a teaching and reasoning tool in complex algebra and analysis. The key words here are *simple* and *Cartesian* -- a polar plot has a slightly different reasoning behind it and so won't do.

**My question is how to draw this in Python in a Jupyter notebook?** I don't find the matplotlib API very intuitive or useful, or at least not the demonstrations I've seen. I assume I have seen overly complicated drawings or that there's a simpler plotting library that can draw this diagram easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A turtle rendering of your diagram. Nothing clever turtle-wise, just step-by-step drawing of the image:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT = ('Times', 18, 'italic')

def inscribe(text):
    color = turtle.pencolor()
    turtle.pencolor('black')
    turtle.write(text, font=FONT)
    turtle.pencolor(color)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-2, -2, 2, 2)  # around the unit circle
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle('classic', visible=False)
turtle.width(2)

# X Axis Real
turtle.goto(-1.25, 0)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(2.5)
turtle.penup()
turtle.stamp()
inscribe('x')

# Y Axis Imaginary
turtle.goto(0, -1.25)
turtle.setheading(90)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(2.5)
turtle.penup()
turtle.stamp()
inscribe('y')

# Circle
turtle.width(1)
turtle.goto(0, -1)
turtle.color('red')
turtle.setheading(0)

for _ in range(72):
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(1, 360 / 144)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.circle(1, 360 / 144)

# Theta
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(0.1, 0)
inscribe(u"\u03B8")

# Angle
turtle.home()
turtle.setheading(60)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(1)
turtle.dot(8)
inscribe("x + iy")
turtle.sety(0)
turtle.home()

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a bit verbose, but may work well for teaching purposes. Let me play with this approach and try to fold it into the lesson...

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you can just break down the Argand diagram into a set of geometric shapes, and just draw those with the Turtle library or Pygame, with functions such as pygame.draw.polygon(). Use these functions and line drawing functions to imitate an Argand diagram.

You could also implement a function in which you input a complex number, and its coefficients are used to determine the lengths of certain lines in the diagram. Good luck!